# Laravel 8.83: Dynamic columns in table

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, dynamic-columns

In the application, we have 2 modules called "Type" and "Lists".

When the user created in type, it will be display in the creating of lists.

**For example**

```
There's 2 data in type: Price & Unit of Measurement
```

Now upon creating in lists those added in types will be display as select.

Below picture is the expected output:

[image]

I tried what I've searched in the internet but it didn't work. It says

[image]

For reference: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/create-columns-in-a-table-dynamically

**CONTROLLER**

```
$items      = ['another_test1','another_test'];
foreach ($items as $i => $item) {
    # code...
    // if($i == 1){
        if (Schema::hasColumn('approvals', $item)) {
            Schema::table('users', function (Blueprint $table) use ($item){
               $table->dropColumn($item);
            });
        }else{
            Schema::table('approvals', function (Blueprint $table) use ($item) {
                $table->longText($item);
            });
        }
    // }
}
```

Question: How do I make a dynamic columns in a table?

Answer (score 0):

I think it's better to use another table that stores your dynamic fields and it has 2 columns

For example table name **custom_fields**

the columns are :

**field_name**

**field_value**

Whenever a new field comes up you insert it with its value

```
CustomField::create(['field_name' => 'type','field_value' => 'price');
```

Wordpress uses that logic too

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I just removed the Blueprint and it worked

```
$items      = ['another_test1','another_test'];
foreach ($items as $i => $item) {
    # code...
    // if($i == 1){
        if (Schema::hasColumn('approvals', $item)) {
            Schema::table('users', function ($table) use ($item){
               $table->dropColumn($item);
            });
        }else{
            Schema::table('approvals', function ($table) use ($item) {
                $table->longText($item);
            });
        }
    // }
}
```